# Pages like xyz.html are being directed to xyz.html/abc.html in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm having a redirect issue in my website and I'm not fluent in .htaccess and Apache programming so I don't know how to fix it. I'd appreciate any help you can give me! I'd really like a permanent solution and not a redirect as I'm trying to preserve link juice as well.

I've found these issues listed in GSC as not found (404). There are a huge number of redirects to pages like the below examples that don't exist. Here are a few:

```
www.example.com/equipment-guides.html/helpdesk.html
www.example.com/shelf.html/racking.html
www.example.com/shelves.html/racks.html
```

Each .html page DOES exist on its own (such as https://www.example.com/equipment guides.html and https://www.example.com/helpdesk.html)

Here is part of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R]

#AddType text/x-server-parsed-html .html for php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
AddDefaultCharset utf-8


# redirect html pages to the root domain
# RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [NC,R,L]
RewriteRule ^index.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# RedirectMatch permanent "^(.*\.html)/.*" "$1"
# RedirectMatch permanent "^(.*\.php)/.*" "$1"
# RewriteRule ^(.*\.html)/.* [R=404,L]
# RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)/.* [R=404,L]
```

Any idea where this went wrong? Thanks for the help!

Some of the commented out lines were my experiements while trying to figure it out. Recently I thought commenting out the below two lines would work but I'm not sure they have, although I haven't gotten the error since 11-25-22 (10 days):

```
# RewriteRule ^(.*\.html)/.* [R=404,L]
# RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)/.* [R=404,L]
```

Comment: "There are a huge number of **redirects** to pages like" - "redirects"? You need to find the underlying cause why these URLs have been discovered in the first place as it could indicate a problem with your internal linking. Only then should you implement a "redirect" in `.htaccess` to resolve the issue (but that's only necessary if these URLs have actually been indexed - unlikely - or linked to by third parties).

Comment: "I'd really like a permanent solution and not a redirect as I'm trying to preserve link juice" - Once you've resolved the underlying issue then a "redirect" is probably the best option to "preserve link juice" - as I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'd really like to know if there is something in my htaccess file that could possibly create these typs of pages - abs.html/xyz.html with the two html pages in one url. Is there a code issue? Maybe with a $ or a / ?